# How can I determine the position of an XML instance in an XMLList in ActionScript3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, e4x

What it says on the tin:  I have an XMLList, and I want to find where in it a particular XML item falls.  First index is good enough for my purposes.

Note that I have no problem writing a function to do this by hand... but I was hoping that the API has something buried somewhere that'll do it for me.  I didn't see it, though.

Comment: Give us some code to work with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the xmllist until you find one that matches, then return the index in your loop (for loop with an index).

Comment: Yeah, that's the by-hand method.  I was hoping there'd be a method in the E4X API to do it.

Comment: Well, maybe the issue is: Why do you want to know the index? Maybe there's a way to solve your problem without it. It's certainly easy to find particular items using e4x

Answer (score 1):

Without a code example it's a bit difficult to know what you're trying to do exactly, but maybe [XML.childIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/XML.html#childIndex()) could the solution?

Comment: That will find me the index of the child in the element that is its parent, but not its position in an XMLList that may be the result of a query.